# Disable account creation with OAuth

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0

Using the standard OAuth functionality provided in a ASP.NET Project I want users to be able to connect their account to Facebook and GMail accounts but by default you can also register a new account by using the external log in links and I want to disable this.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing this in RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs in class `ProcessProviderResult()`

```
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // User is already authenticated, add the external login and redirect to return url
            OpenAuth.AddAccountToExistingUser(ProviderName, ProviderUserId, ProviderUserName, User.Identity.Name);
            RedirectToReturnUrl();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Register.aspx");
            // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
            // userName.Text = authResult.UserName;
        }
```

If user is not authenticated I redirect the user to the normal registration page.